# MYSQL select birthday based on age range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MYSQL table where I store birthday with the datatype date. Rows:

```
birthday
--------
1989-08-08
```

I want to select users with age between 18 and 25 years. I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE birthday <= now() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR and
      birthday >= now() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

This should return the above row as It fits in the range between 18 and 25 but MYSQL assumes that it's 26 years old as it's between 25 and 26

Comment: didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: i got part of the solution and used it in this question :)

Comment: If you got an answer for the other (extremely similar) question you should accept _that_ answer to make clear that this is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

25 years ago was 1989-09-27 and 1989-08-08 is less than 1989-09-27 so it will not be returned. If you want people who are currently 25 but not yet 26, change to `INTERVAL 26 year + INTERVAL 1 DAY`;

Comment: what about `> INTERVAL 26 YEAR` without the `=`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this logic: if person is 18 years old then true:

```
(birthday + INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= now() < (birthday + INTERVAL 19 YEAR)
```

if person is 25 yers old then true:

```
(birthday + INTERVAL 25 YEAR) <= now() < (birthday + INTERVAL 26 YEAR)
```

By this logic to get users with age between 18 and 25 years:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE birthday <= now() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR and
      birthday > now() - INTERVAL 26 YEAR
```