# Fetch data from table depending on date of birth

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, fetch, codeigniter-3

Hello I'm working on a website and I have students in my database table called 'jongeren' which means students.
What I'm trying to do is make a list for students which are 18 years or older. In the table jongeren I have a column which is: 'geboortedatum' and that means date of birth. So I only want to echo all the students in a view that are born before 27 march 2000 but I don't know how to do that..

Right now I'm just echoing all the students like this:

model:

```
 public function fetch_data()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('jongeren');
        //Haal alle gegevens uit jongeren tabel en sla op in $query variabele
        return $query;
    }
```

controller:

```
public function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('Main_model');
            $data['fetch_data'] = $this->Main_model->fetch_data();
            $this->load->view('ingeschreven_jongeren', $data);
        }
```

view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Voornaam</th>
                    <th>Achternaam</th>
                    <th>Email adres</th>
                    <th>Woonplaats</th>
                    <th>Postcode</th>
                    <th>Straat</th>
                    <th>Huisnummer</th>
                    <th>Geboortedatum</th>
                    <th>Inschrijfdatum</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    foreach($fetch_data->result() as $row)
                    {
                ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->jongere_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->voornaam; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->achternaam; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->woonplaats; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->postcode; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->straat; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->huisnummer; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->geboortedatum; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->inschrijfdatum; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <!--Als er geen data in jongeren tabel zit echo dan dit bericht--> 
                        <td colspan="3"> Geen data gevonden </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
```

So yeah that is my code that shows all the students. I probably should change something in my model function so that it only fetch data for students that were born before 27 march 2000?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html says there is a get_where function, try that, hope it helps.

Comment: Check [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078240/mysql-select-birthday-based-on-age-range), maybe it will help you:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy thing to do if your database is MySQL or MariaDB using INTERVAL:

```
$query = $this->db->query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM jongeren 
    WHERE geboortedatum - CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
');
```

This assumes your column is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype. So a lot of assumptions are made here.

Comment: `geboortedatum < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR'`
You want to find users older than this date ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out